# When calling "ActiveRecord::Base.create", how to call "create"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, I create new table.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Then I create new record. When calling `Post.create`, `create` is the method defined in `persistance.rb`.

```
Post.method(:create).source_location
=> #["D:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/persistence.rb", 29]
```

Class `Base`is defined in `base.rb` in the same directory.

Say seeing the files,module `Persistance`and class `Base`is the same level in the `ActiveRecord`.

So how can `Post` call `create`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to separate between classical hierarchical inheritance and parallel inheritance.

In Ruby classes can only inherit from a single class but they can include many modules. This is what is commonly known as mixins or traits in other languages.

```
module A
  def hello(name = "World")
    "Hello #{name}"
  end
end

module B
  def goodbye(name = "World"))
    "Goodbye #{name}"
  end
end

class Base
  include A
  include B
end

class Foo < Base
end

foo = Foo.new
puts foo.hello # => Hello World
puts foo.goodbye # => Goodbye World
```

In this case `ActiveRecord::Base` includes many modules such as `ActiveRecord::Persistence`  which provide its functionality.

Your also confusing the concept of namespaces and inheritance. Ruby does not have actual namespaces (with its own keyword) but you can encapsulate most kinds of objects by placing them in a module:

```
module Foo
  class Bar
  end

  module Baz
    class Bar
    end
  end
end
```

This does not effect inheritance. For example in this case there is no actual connection between `Foo::Bar` and `Foo::Baz::Bar`. There is also no direct correlation between the file a class or module is defined in and how the inheritance tree works. Ruby will happily let you shove everything into a single file.

Comment: Sorry. I think that Rails works like below.  

`module ActiveRecord

  module Persistence

    module ClassMethod
     
      def create
      end

    end

  end

  class Base
    include Persistence
  end

end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
end

Post.create title: "First Post"`

This means that the method `create` in ClassMethod is class method of the class `Post` but not instance method.

Your explain is about instance method.

But I cannot find the source code.

Comment: They are not nice to look.sorry,I cannot insert `\n`.

Comment: You should start with something like http://www.tryruby.org. As this is more about basic Ruby than Rails. The exact same thing applies to class methods but from where you are knowledgewise I doubt you would understand the example with class methods as defining class methods in module is quite different.

Comment: Thats where the ClassMethods modules come in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106618/discussion-between-messi-and-max).

Comment: Because ActiveRecord::Persistence extends ActiveSupport::concern which extends the Base class with the ClassMethods module when it is included. But this is way past your level of understanding - you should atleast have a grasp of how oop in Ruby works before trying to understand the Rails internals which are quite complex. Really do some basic ruby tutorials like tryruby and ruby monks. I'm not going to hand hold you.

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveRecord::Base` includes `ActiveRecord::Persistence`, as you can see in the sources:

```
  class Base
    # [...]

    include Core
    include Persistence
    include ReadonlyAttributes
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L285